# ax.set_xlabel and ax.set_ylabel not working with pandas plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have found similar questions previously, but I haven't managed to find an answer that has worked for me.

I am plotting directly from my data frame and would like to label my axis. This is the code I am using:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
ax.set_ylabel("Normalised Vertical Acceleration")
data.plot(kind='line', x='time', y='accel_y', ax=ax)
```

The graph generated only has "cycle" as the x-axis label and no y-axis label. Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Or is there a better method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `ax`? Why don't you axes returned by `diff.plot(...)`?

Comment: ax are my axes which I have defined previously. I use the same axes for all the plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer: Based on your updated question

You don't need additionally `ax = plt.gca()`. Then, first plot the data and then set the axis labels

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data.plot(kind='line', x='time', y='accel_y', ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
ax.set_ylabel("Normalised Vertical Acceleration")
```

Comment: Your solution did not work for me. I have changed the code snippet to show a fuller example of what I mean. In this example, the y label sets, but the x label does not.

Comment: @ShrutiTurner : Try my edited answer. If that still doesn't work, then read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's worked - thanks! I guess the order messed it up.

Answer (score 0):

@Sheldore's answer didn't work for me.
Instead, we need to use the inbuild function parameter:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data.plot(kind='line', x='time', y='accel_y', ax=ax, 
     ylabel="Normalised Vertical Acceleration",
     xlabel="Time (s)")
```

I would report this as a bug to Pandas, which might be version-specific.